Sinon with TypeScript Invalid Use of 'arguments'
I'm trying to use Sinon with Mocha and Chai for testing in a TypeScript project, but TypeScript gives me the following error:

TS1215: Invalid use of 'arguments'. Modules are automatically in strict mode.

Looking at the code that it's talking about, the error makes sense, as "arguments" is already reserved, so you couldn't have a variable named that.

/**
 * @callback NextTick
 * @param {VoidVarArgsFunc} callback - the callback to run
 * @param {...*} arguments - optional arguments to call the callback with
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * @callback SetImmediate
 * @param {VoidVarArgsFunc} callback - the callback to run
 * @param {...*} arguments - optional arguments to call the callback with
 * @returns {NodeImmediate}
 */

You'd think, then, that this would be a common issue, but I'm seeing nothing in my searches related to this.
Here's my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app*": [ "./src/app/*", "./src/app/*/index" ], 
      "@lib*": [ "./src/lib/*", "./src/lib/*/index" ],
      "@components*": [ "./src/app/components/*", "./src/app/components/*/index" ]
    },

    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.core",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.reflect",
      "es2015.iterable",
      "es2015.symbol",
      "es2015.symbol.wellknown"
    ]
  },

  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "static", 
    "node_modules",
    "webpack.config.js"
  ],

  "compileOnSave": false
}


And the test file (ignore use of nameof, it's an additional transformer that functions similarly to C#'s nameof keyword)
import { expect } from "chai";
import { createStubInstance, stub, spy, type SinonStub } from "sinon";
import { RequestService } from "./RequestService";
import { SecurityService } from "./SecurityService";

describe("app", () => {

  describe("services", () => {

    describe(nameof(RequestService), () => {

      let originalFetch = fetch;

      let requestService: RequestService | undefined;

      let fetchStub: SinonStub<[input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined], Promise<Response>> | undefined;

      suiteSetup(() => {
        fetchStub = stub(window, "fetch");
        fetchStub.returns(Promise.resolve(new Response("[]", { status: 200, headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" } })))

        requestService = new RequestService(createStubInstance(SecurityService));
      });

      suiteTeardown(() => {
        window["fetch"] = originalFetch;
      });

      it("should exist", () => {

        expect(RequestService).to.exist;

      });

      it("should make requests using fetch", () => {
        const fetchSpy = spy(fetchStub);

        requestService?.get("http://foo.bar.baz");

        expect(fetchSpy?.called).to.be.true;
      });

    });

  });

})

I also have @types/sinon installed as a dev dependency.
So I guess I'm wondering what I can do to get past this error.

In what file is that error? And on what code?

@AlexWayne Oddly, it's complaining about node_modules\sinon\pkg\sinon-esm.js. I have the offending lines included above. They're block comments, and I wouldn't think TypeScript would parse those. Especially if it already has typings included...

Your config has node_modules excluded, so it shouldn't be type checking those. When exactly does this error come up? In your IDE (probably not since you probably won't open a file in node_modules) or when you run a command? If so, what command? Is that command reading your typescript config properly?

@AlexWayne this occurs when I do "npx instant-mocha src/**/*.spec.ts --reporter spec". The instant-mocha package integrates my webpack build with mocha tests. The error is emitted from ts-loader, which is using my tsconfig.json file and TypeScript 5.4.5

Solved the error by creating an alias in my webpack.config.js file to target sinon/lib/sinon.js instead of sinon/lib/sinon-esm.js that's targeted by default. Not sure why that fixed it, considering that sinon-esm.js just references sinon.js, but it works now.
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
